# Spatial clustering with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, clustering

I'm looking for spatial clustering algorithm for using it within PostGIS-enabled database for point features. I'm going to write plpgsql function that takes distance between points within the same cluster as input. At the output function returns array of clusters. The most obvious solution is to build buffer zones specified distance around the feature and search for features into this buffer. If such features exist then continue to build a buffer around them, etc. If such features not exist that means cluster building is completed. Maybe there are some clever solutions?

Comment: There is a huge variety of clustering methods because of the differing nature of data and different purposes of clustering.  For an overview of what's out there and for some easy reading about what others are doing to cluster distance matrices, [search the CV@SE site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[clustering]+%2Bdistance).  In fact, ["choosing clustering method"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3713) is almost an exact duplicate of yours and has good answers.

Comment: +1 to the question because finding an actual PostGIS SQL example instead of links to algorithms is mission impossible for anything other than basic grid clustering, especially for more exotic clusterings like [MCL](http://micans.org/mcl/)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

There are at least two good clustering methods for PostGIS: *k*-means (via `kmeans-postgresql` extension) or clustering geometries within a threshold distance (PostGIS 2.2)

---

## 1) *k*-means with `kmeans-postgresql`

**Installation:** You need to compile and install this from source code, which is easier to do on *NIX than Windows (I don't know where to start). If you have PostgreSQL installed from packages, make sure you also have the development packages (e.g., `postgresql-devel` for CentOS).

Download, extract, build and install:

```
wget http://api.pgxn.org/dist/kmeans/1.1.0/kmeans-1.1.0.zip
unzip kmeans-1.1.0.zip
cd kmeans-1.1.0/
make USE_PGXS=1
sudo make install
```

Enable the extension in a database (using psql, pgAdmin, etc.):

```
CREATE EXTENSION kmeans;
```

**Usage/Example:** You should have a table of points somewhere (I drew a bunch of pseudo random points in QGIS). Here is an example with what I did:

```
SELECT kmeans, count(*), ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
FROM (
  SELECT kmeans(ARRAY[ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)], 5) OVER (), geom
  FROM rand_point
) AS ksub
GROUP BY kmeans
ORDER BY kmeans;
```

the `5` I provided in the second argument of the `kmeans` window function is the *K* integer to produce five clusters. You can change this to whatever integer you want.

Below is the 31 pseudo random points I drew and the five centroids with the label showing the count in each cluster. This was created using the above SQL query.

[image: Kmeans]

---

You can also attempt to illustrate where these clusters are with [ST_MinimumBoundingCircle](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html):

```
SELECT kmeans, ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_Collect(geom)) AS circle
FROM (
  SELECT kmeans(ARRAY[ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)], 5) OVER (), geom
  FROM rand_point
) AS ksub
GROUP BY kmeans
ORDER BY kmeans;
```

[image: Kmeans2]

---

## 2) Clustering within a threshold distance with `ST_ClusterWithin`

[This aggregate function](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html) is included with PostGIS 2.2, and returns an array of GeometryCollections where all the components are within a distance of each other.

Here is an example use, where a distance of 100.0 is the threshold that results in 5 different clusters:

```
SELECT row_number() over () AS id,
  ST_NumGeometries(gc),
  gc AS geom_collection,
  ST_Centroid(gc) AS centroid,
  ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(gc) AS circle,
  sqrt(ST_Area(ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(gc)) / pi()) AS radius
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 100)) gc
  FROM rand_point
) f;
```

[image: ClusterWithin100]

The largest middle cluster has a enclosing circle radius of 65.3 units or about 130, which is larger than the threshold. This is because the individual distances between the member geometries is less than the threshold, so it ties it together as one larger cluster.

Comment: Great, these modifications will help for the installation :-) However I fear I can't really use that extension in the end because (if I understood correctly), it needs an hardcoded magic number of clusters, which is fine with static data precause you can fine-tune it in advance but wouldn't fit me for clustering arbitrary (due to various filters) data sets, e.g. the large gap in the 10-points cluster on the last image. However this will help other people too because (afaik), this is the only existing SQL example (except the one liners on the extension's homepage) for that extension.

Comment: (ah you replied at the same time I deleted the previous comment to reformulate it, sorry)

Comment: For kmeans clustering you need to specify the number of clusters in advance; I'm curious if there are alternative algorithms where the number of clusters is not required though.

Comment: Version 1.1.0 is now available: http://api.pgxn.org/dist/kmeans/1.1.0/kmeans-1.1.0.zip

Comment: how do you visualize it?

Comment: @andi many, many different ways. I normally use QGIS.

Comment: How to install kmeans module in postgres in window 7 machine.

Comment: @Sanjayr it's possible, but very difficult to do, requiring non-free compilers and expertise on how to use them. It's much simpler to do with Linux, even a VM running on Windows.

Comment: @maxd no. Given A = πr², then r=√(A/π).

Comment: @Mike T How do you visualize GeometryCollection datatype in QGIS?

Comment: I answered to my question here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230719/20843
I forgot to say thanks Mike!

Comment: I got ERROR: function kmeans(double precision[], integer) does not exist

Comment: @Luffydude you need to revise your installation steps, and if you had issues, make a new question to address it.

Answer (score 34):

I've written function that calculates clusters of features based on distance between them and build convex hull over this features:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_domains_n(lname varchar, geom varchar, gid varchar, radius numeric)
    RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
DECLARE
    lid_new    integer;
    dmn_number integer := 1;
    outr       record;
    innr       record;
    r          record;
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT '||gid||', '||geom||' FROM '||lname;
    ALTER TABLE tmp ADD COLUMN dmn integer;
    ALTER TABLE tmp ADD COLUMN chk boolean DEFAULT FALSE;
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmp SET dmn = '||dmn_number||', chk = FALSE WHERE '||gid||' = (SELECT MIN('||gid||') FROM tmp)';

    LOOP
        LOOP
            FOR outr IN EXECUTE 'SELECT '||gid||' AS gid, '||geom||' AS geom FROM tmp WHERE dmn = '||dmn_number||' AND NOT chk' LOOP
                FOR innr IN EXECUTE 'SELECT '||gid||' AS gid, '||geom||' AS geom FROM tmp WHERE dmn IS NULL' LOOP
                    IF ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(outr.geom, 4326), 3785), ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(innr.geom, 4326), 3785), radius) THEN
                    --IF ST_DWithin(outr.geom, innr.geom, radius) THEN
                        EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmp SET dmn = '||dmn_number||', chk = FALSE WHERE '||gid||' = '||innr.gid;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
                EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmp SET chk = TRUE WHERE '||gid||' = '||outr.gid;
            END LOOP;
            SELECT INTO r dmn FROM tmp WHERE dmn = dmn_number AND NOT chk LIMIT 1;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
       END LOOP;
       SELECT INTO r dmn FROM tmp WHERE dmn IS NULL LIMIT 1;
       IF FOUND THEN
           dmn_number := dmn_number + 1;
           EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmp SET dmn = '||dmn_number||', chk = FALSE WHERE '||gid||' = (SELECT MIN('||gid||') FROM tmp WHERE dmn IS NULL LIMIT 1)';
       ELSE
           EXIT;
       END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect('||geom||')) FROM tmp GROUP by dmn';

    RETURN;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example of using this function:

```
SELECT * FROM get_domains_n('poi', 'wkb_geometry', 'ogc_fid', 14000) AS g(gm geometry)
```

'poi' - name of layer, 'wkb_geometry' - name of geometry column, 'ogc_fid' - primary key of table, 14000 - cluster distance.

The result of using this function:

[image]

Comment: Great! Could you add an example of how to user your function too? Thanks!

Comment: I've modified little bit of source code and have added example of using function.

Comment: Just tried using this on postgres 9.1 and line "                FOR innr IN EXECUTE 'SELECT '||gid||' AS gid, '||geom||' AS geom FROM tmp WHERE dmn IS NULL' LOOP
" yields the following error. Any ideas ?     ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Comment: I'm unsure as how to use this code in PG (PostGIS n00b) in my table. where could I start to understand this syntax? I have a table with lats and lons that I want to cluster

Comment: First of all you have to build `geometry` column within your table, not to store lonlat separately and make column with unique values (IDs).

Comment: ok I managed to change the function to support my separate lat,lon columns: https://gist.github.com/mgiraldo/3f810f49c09d3311e964 one question: how do I make these plots/graphs as shown in the answer?

Comment: Use `SELECT INTO` for creating new table with clusters. Then you can open it from any desktop GIS, QGIS for example.

Comment: thanks... does this particular algorithm have a name?

Comment: No name. Can you confirm this algorithm works on your data?

Comment: confirmed... I will post a link once it is live

Comment: I faced this Error `NOTICE:  table "tmp" does not exist, skipping
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp"
PL/pgSQL function get_domains_n(character varying,character varying,character varying,numeric) line 10 at SQL statement
ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (558507 146203 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_domains_n(character varying,character varying,character varying,numeric) line 20 at IF

********** Error **********`

Comment: @Sanjayr is your data in geographic SRS?

Comment: No its projected one. SRS 27700

Comment: I am really liking this Function. The results are great. Many Thanks! I am just trying to understand its logic a little more. Does the algorithm go from point to point to point, and add each to the cluster if it is under the radius distance? In other words, if you set the radius to 1000m, then have 11 points in a line, each 500m distance from the next, will it add each point to the cluster? So in the end, you have a cluster 5000m long?

Comment: @maw269 you are right - in the end you will have one cluster of 5000 m long because the individual distances between the points is equal to cluster distance.

Answer (score 13):

So far, the most promising I found is this extension for K-means clustering as a window function: http://pgxn.org/dist/kmeans/

However I haven't been able to install it successfully yet.

---

Otherwise, for basic grid clustering, you could use [SnapToGrid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html).

```
SELECT
    array_agg(id) AS ids,
    COUNT( position ) AS count,
    ST_AsText( ST_Centroid(ST_Collect( position )) ) AS center,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
    ST_SnapToGrid( ST_SetSRID(position, 4326), 22.25, 11.125)
ORDER BY
    count DESC
;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use Kmeans solution more easily with [ST_ClusterKMeans](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterKMeans.html) method that's available in postgis from 2.3
Example:

```
SELECT kmean, count(*), ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(geom), 4326) as bbox 
FROM
(
    SELECT ST_ClusterKMeans(geom, 20) OVER() AS kmean, ST_Centroid(geom) as geom
    FROM sls_product 
) tsub
GROUP BY kmean;
```

The bounding box of features is used as cluster geometry in the example above.
The first image shows the original geometries and the second one is the result of select above.

[image: Original geometries]
[image: Feature clusters]

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @MikeT answer...

For MS Windows:

Requirements:

- Any Visual C++ Express version such as [this](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjLvqGMzb7KAhUBVj4KHdbhAFYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2F%3Flinkid%3D7729279&usg=AFQjCNGYfzKyei1iWVacHb8KFY3v-T6KQQ&bvm=bv.112454388,d.cWw&cad=rja)
- The [kmeans-postgresql](https://github.com/umitanuki/kmeans-postgresql/archive/master.zip) module.

What you will do:

- Tweak the source code to export the kmeans function to a DLL.
- Compile the source code with `cl.exe` compiler to generate a DLL with `kmeans` function.
- Put the generated DLL into PostgreSQL\lib folder.
- Then you can "create" (link) the UDF into PostgreSQL through SQL command.

Steps:

1. Download & install/extract requirements.
2. Open the `kmeans.c` in any editor:

   1. After `#include` lines define DLLEXPORT macro with:

      ```
      #if defined(_WIN32)
          #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
      #else
         #define DLLEXPORT
      #endif
      ```
   2. Put `DLLEXPORT` before each of these lines:

      ```
      PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(kmeans_with_init);
      PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(kmeans);

      extern Datum kmeans_with_init(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
      extern Datum kmeans(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
      ```
3. Open Visual C++ Command Line.
4. In the command line:

   1. Go to the extracted `kmeans-postgresql`.
   2. Set your POSTGRESPATH, mine for example is: `SET POSTGRESPATH=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5`
   3. Run

      ```
      cl.exe /I"%POSTGRESPATH%\include" /I"%POSTGRESPATH%\include\server" /I"%POSTGRESPATH%\include\server\port\win32" /I"%POSTGRESPATH%\include\server\port\win32_msvc" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include" /LD kmeans.c "%POSTGRESPATH%\lib\postgres.lib"
      ```
5. Copy the `kmeans.dll` to `%POSTGRESPATH%\lib`
6. Now run the SQL command in your database to "CREATE" the function.

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION kmeans(float[], int) RETURNS int
   AS '$libdir/kmeans'
   LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT WINDOW;

   CREATE FUNCTION kmeans(float[], int, float[]) RETURNS int
   AS '$libdir/kmeans', 'kmeans_with_init'
   LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT WINDOW;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Bottom up clustering solution from [Get a single cluster from cloud of points with maximum diameter in postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115715/36886) which involves no dynamic queries.

```
CREATE TYPE pt AS (
    gid character varying(32),
    the_geom geometry(Point))
```

and a type with cluster id

```
CREATE TYPE clustered_pt AS (
    gid character varying(32),
    the_geom geometry(Point)
    cluster_id int)
```

Next the algorithm function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buc(points pt[], radius integer)
RETURNS SETOF clustered_pt AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    srid int;
    joined_clusters int[];

BEGIN

--If there's only 1 point, don't bother with the loop.
IF array_length(points,1)<2 THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT gid, the_geom, 1 FROM unnest(points);
    RETURN;
END IF;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS points2 (LIKE pt) ON COMMIT DROP;

BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE points2 ADD COLUMN cluster_id serial;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_column THEN --do nothing. Exception comes up when using this function multiple times
END;

TRUNCATE points2;
    --inserting points in
INSERT INTO points2(gid, the_geom)
    (SELECT (unnest(points)).* ); 

--Store the srid to reconvert points after, assumes all points have the same SRID
srid := ST_SRID(the_geom) FROM points2 LIMIT 1;

UPDATE points2 --transforming points to a UTM coordinate system so distances will be calculated in meters.
SET the_geom =  ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,26986);

--Adding spatial index
CREATE INDEX points_index
ON points2
USING gist
(the_geom);

ANALYZE points2;

LOOP
    --If the smallest maximum distance between two clusters is greater than 2x the desired cluster radius, then there are no more clusters to be formed
    IF (SELECT ST_MaxDistance(ST_Collect(a.the_geom),ST_Collect(b.the_geom))  FROM points2 a, points2 b
        WHERE a.cluster_id <> b.cluster_id
        GROUP BY a.cluster_id, b.cluster_id 
        ORDER BY ST_MaxDistance(ST_Collect(a.the_geom),ST_Collect(b.the_geom)) LIMIT 1)
        > 2 * radius
    THEN
        EXIT;
    END IF;

    joined_clusters := ARRAY[a.cluster_id,b.cluster_id]
        FROM points2 a, points2 b
        WHERE a.cluster_id <> b.cluster_id
        GROUP BY a.cluster_id, b.cluster_id
        ORDER BY ST_MaxDistance(ST_Collect(a.the_geom),ST_Collect(b.the_geom)) 
        LIMIT 1;

    UPDATE points2
    SET cluster_id = joined_clusters[1]
    WHERE cluster_id = joined_clusters[2];

    --If there's only 1 cluster left, exit loop
    IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cluster_id) FROM points2) < 2 THEN
        EXIT;

    END IF;

END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT gid, ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom, srid)::geometry(point), cluster_id FROM points2;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Usage:

```
WITH subq AS(
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG((gid, the_geom)::pt) AS points
    FROM data
    GROUP BY collection_id)
SELECT (clusters).* FROM 
    (SELECT buc(points, radius) AS clusters FROM subq
) y;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to display in QGIS the result of the PostGIS query given in 2) in [this anwser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11778/20843)

As QGIS doesn't handle neither geometrycollections nor different datatypes in the same geometry column, I've created two layers, one for clusters and one for clustered points.

First for clusters, you only need polygons, other results are lonely points :

```
SELECT id,countfeature,circle FROM (SELECT row_number() over () AS id,
  ST_NumGeometries(gc) as countfeature,
  ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(gc) AS circle
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(the_geom, 100)) gc
  FROM rand_point
) f) a WHERE ST_GeometryType(circle) = 'ST_Polygon'
```

Then for clustered points, you need to transform geometrycollections in multipoint :

```
SELECT row_number() over () AS id,
  ST_NumGeometries(gc) as countfeature,
  ST_CollectionExtract(gc,1) AS multipoint
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(the_geom, 100)) gc
  FROM rand_point
) f
```

Some points are at same coordinates so the label could be confusing.

[image: Clustering in QGIS]