# Markers > 50000 Overlays on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I would like to know the way to overlay 50000 markers on OpenLayers, and would like to know how many OpenLayers can support?

Comment: Also have a look at this question for how to do server-side clustering: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41855/what-are-my-options-for-server-side-clustering-using-open-source-gis-tools

Answer (score 2):

According to your question :

Browsers can't handle moving around a DOM with more than a few hundred elements at once. I highly recommend figuring out a way to limit yourself to under 500 markers (Firefox) or 50 markers (IE6).

Please go though [FAQ's](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Markers)