# Installing knn on PostgreSQL for windows

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, clustering, extensions

I am trying to install the extension KNN for clustering as an extension on my PostgreSQL database.

I have downloaded the file

> http://www.pgxn.org/tag/analysis

I found instructions on how to install the package on windows here

> http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/216-PostgreSQL-9.1-Exploring-Extensions.html

However the file i downloaded does not contain the file make or make install.

Can anyone help. It doesn't need to be for this particular extension as im sure its the same for all extensions and it would be a nice bit of knowledge to have

KNN is a clustering algorithm which groups data points based on their attributes into clusters or groups which are similar. My data set is a geographic data set with point information. Classic KNN doesn't treat information like latitude and longitude as spatial elements but as regular attributes (in this case numbers)

The extension i am trying to install uses the logic of KNN but opens it up so that it also incorporates the spatial information i.e. where the data points are on a map of Europe to cluster the information. There are methods for doing this using Python and R but it is easiest to implement in PostgreSQL and then visualize in QGIS. An example was outlined in the thread ***[Spatial clustering with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis)*** in these forums previously but it was for linux/unix systems and i wish to modify it so that i can incorporate it into my windows PC for my particular geographic dataset

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's not clear from your post if you are installing the extension on a Windows machine or a Linux/Unix based system? 'make' and 'make install' are GNU Linux tools that create executables from a Makefile. The Makefile is included in the downloaded file you cited above.

Comment: hi dmci. I'm trying to get K-NN extension installed on a windows machine. Do you think its possible or is this knn specifically set up for Linux/Unix Systems. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Why do you think this is a GIS-related question? If you can edit your question (just click edit below your question) to make it relevant to this site, that would be useful.