# Merge point features within a given radius

Tags: qgis, merge, generalization

I have a file in QGIS with 5000 points. Some of the points are really close to each other (5m). How can I cluster the point features to one point feature if they are within 5m? The new points should be centroids from the given points.

Comment: How would you like to deal with a situation where you had 50-60 points that were each within 5 m of another point, but spread out over, say 200m overall? Should they then all be merged to a single point?

Comment: Do you want to _delete_ the points or overlay them atop one another?

Comment: Does _merge the point features to one point feature_ mean calculate a new (barycentric) point feature or discard all the points except one on some basis?

Comment: @afalciano I want to create the centroid of the point features, like the way you described in your answer.

Comment: @Simbamangu It is not really the case in my dataset, that the points are spread out over 200m and are within 5m distance.

Comment: [Spatial Clustering with PostGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis) provides a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible approach consists in the following steps:

1. draw a **buffer** of 5m around points;
2. **dissolve** the buffers which overlap;
3. calculate the **centroids** of dissolved buffers.

You can choose the tools with which you're more comfortable.

**Example**
For instance, using GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite you can calculate the buffer around your `points.shp`:

```
ogr2ogr buffers.shp points.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry,5) from points"
```

Then, calculate the clusters (dissolved buffers):

```
ogr2ogr clusters.shp buffers.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) from buffers" -explodecollections
```

Finally, calculate `result_points.shp`:

```
ogr2ogr result_points.shp clusters.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT Centroid(geometry) FROM clusters"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2013/04/tutorial-nearest-neighbor-analysis.html

- Compute a Nearest Neighbour Analysis for your dataset
- Add the resultant table into QGIS and join it to your dataset
- Export your data into Excel and Sort/Filter it by distance.
- Select all your data rows where the distance is <5 m
- Select Data -> Delete duplicates
- Import back into QGIS

Where any points are within 5 m of each other, this simple process will remove one and keep the other!