# Find area with highest relative density of one type of object

Tags: postgis, query, density, spatial-query

I'm using PostgreSQL/PostGIS and I have an advanced type of query.

My database contains two types of object - let's say pubs and churches :)

Is there a way that I can find the area with the densest concentration of pubs compared to churches, and vice versa?

I can obviously display this visually with a heatmap, but I just wondered if there was a programmatic way to do this with PostgreSQL? Perhaps the point that is closest to the most churches relative to pubs?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Just to clarify, "...find the area with...": do you actually already have a layer of area boundaries? If so, it should be fairly easy to make the query. If not, hmm, ... i think you're looking at some kind of nearest-neighbor analysis.

Comment: Thanks! I don't currently have a set of areas, but I can add one easily enough. 
However, I'd like an analysis that takes into account the distance between different areas (otherwise I don't really need a spatial database at all, I can just run a normal database query...).

Comment: How about clustering(http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11778/16594)? It does let you find the areas with high density.

Comment: Hm, actually I'm not sure clustering is going to work for my data. Say I look at pubs: if I simply look for clusters among pubs, it's going to find the biggest cluster in the capital city, where there are also the most churches. It's *relative* density I'm interested in, and I don't think clustering can correct for this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if you want relative density then you need something to relate to. Like a grid or city borders.