# Create polygons enclosing same number of points on PostGIS

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, postgis-2.0, geodjango

I  have a geodatabase on Postgis with points representing customers, what i need is give a number of customers, lets say 100 and it need to generate polygons enclosing 100 clients each one. I only have generated a grid but its uniform and don't take in count the number of clients.

---

Yes @John Barça and @underdark your solution of using cluster points and then convex hull can work bot i need to create clusters with same number of points, do u have an idea how this can be done on PostGis?? sample i have 100 points and i want bunches of 10 based on proximity.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question isn't very clear in terms of how your points are distributed, how you want the enclosing polygons to look, etc. If you could add a bit more detail of what you have/what you expect, you are likely to get more response.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "clustering". http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering

Comment: @underdark. I'm not so sure, OP actually wants to generate polygons around points, not just cluster sets of points. I guess you could cluster points and then take the convex hull?

Comment: See @MikeT's excellent answer on [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis) for some ideas.