# How to add attributes to clustered points with Postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I already have found a similar answer here:

[Spatial clustering with PostGIS including attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185348/spatial-clustering-with-postgis-including-attributes)

but grouping after by cluster.

I cluster my data in this way:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 2)))
from (
values 
    (ST_MakePoint(10,9),'mark',20),
    (ST_MakePoint(10,9),'mark',22),
    (ST_MakePoint(10,10),'steve',21),
    (ST_MakePoint(10,13),'john',23)
) T(geom,name,age);
```

that correctly returns:

```
                        st_astext                         
----------------------------------------------------------
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(10 9),POINT(10 9),POINT(10 10))
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(10 13))
```

But what I really need is that once the data is clustered by "location" it needs to pick the first in alphabetical order desc, and if the same name, by the age desc.
A sort of:

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number () over (order by name desc, age desc)
    from (pre-clustered-data) T
) K where row_number = 1;
```

How can I do that with Postgis?

Comment: this actually is a windowing function: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterKMeans.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have PostGIS 2.3 or later, I can't think of a good reason to use `ST_ClusterWithin`. You can perform an equivalent clustering using [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) but without losing your attributes:

```
SELECT
  name,
  age,
  cluster_id,
  geom
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    age,
    geom,
    ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 2) OVER() AS cluster_id,
  FROM my_data
) sq
GROUP BY cluster_id
```

You can then feed the results of the above into whatever process/logic is selecting a representative item from each cluster. (If you're looking to do it in SQL, try computing the `rank` of each name, partitioned by `cluster_id`, and then each `age`, partitioned by `cluster_id` and `name`.)