# Merge buffers PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a points layer arround which I created a buffer of 10m. What I want to do is merge the buffers which intersects each other and the point layer.

I did this to be able to create polygon arround the points which are within 10 m.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getbuffered() RETURNS SETOF sige.buffer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    poly record;
    pts record;
    intersects boolean;
    geom_poly geometry(MultiPolygon,32628);
    geom_fusion geometry(MultiPolygon,32628); 
BEGIN
    FOR pts IN SELECT * FROM sige.object_elevation LOOP
        FOR poly IN SELECT * FROM sige.buffer LOOP
            intersects := (select true from sige.buffer,sige.object_elevation
                            where poly.id<>pts.id and st_intersects(poly.geom,pts.geom));
                if true then
                geom_poly := (select geom from sige.buffer where orig_fid = pts.id);
                end if;
         END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

In this function I am iterating in points layer, then in buffer layer. then I select the features from buffer  which have a different id from the points ones and intersect them. 
If the result is true I want to merge them.

I executed my function that I'm presuming correct but I get this :

```
ERROR: more than one line returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT: SELECT SQL statement (select true from sige.buffer, sige.object_elevation
             where poly.id <> pts.id and st_intersects (poly.geom, pts.geom))
PL / pgsql function getbuffered (), line 10 to assignment
```

What am I'm missing?

Comment: not sure if I get this right...you basically want to cluster points that are within 10m of each other and create a convex hull around each of those clusters? if so, [ST_ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html) should be the better choice than a buffer aproach (using buffers for anything distance related is usually not a good idea)

Comment: Please be sure to always specify the exact PostgreSQL database release and PostGIS version within each question.

Answer (score 1):

*"I did this to be able to create polygon around the points which are within 10 m."* - I'll give it a shot at what I think you want to do, that is "clustering all your points with a cluster distance of 10m and create a convex hull around each cluster"...
To simply draw the minimal enclosing geometry around each cluster, you can do the following, using [ST_ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html) and [ST_ConvexHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html):

```
WITH
  clst AS (
    SELECT ST_ClusterWithin(<geometry_column>, 10) arr
    FROM <your_point_table>
  )

SELECT a.cluster_id,
       ST_ConvexHull(ST_CollectionHomogenize(a.geom)) AS geom
FROM clst,
     unnest(clst.arr) WITH ORDINALITY a(geom, cluster_id)
```

Note: this will return the minimal enclosing geometry of each cluster - that can also be a POINT geometry for a single point that is his own cluster, or a LINESTRING geometry for two points being a cluster! It's a little tricky (some say unadvisable) to work with mixed geometry types in the same table.
As an option, you could only select those clusters that are actually enclosed by a POLYGON:

```
WITH
  clst AS (
    SELECT ST_ClusterWithin(<geometry_column>, 10) arr
    FROM <your_point_table>
  ),

  clst_encl AS (
    SELECT a.cluster_id,
           ST_ConvexHull(ST_CollectionHomogenize(a.geom)) AS geom
    FROM clst,
         unnest(clst.arr) WITH ORDINALITY a(geom, cluster_id)
  )

SELECT *
FROM clst_encl
WHERE GeometryType(geom) = 'POLYGON'
```

with the minor backdraw that the extracted array's ordinals I used as *cluster_id* are not strictly consecutive due to rows being omitted.
You could also opt for simply assigning the *cluster_id* to your original points:

```
WITH
  clst AS (
    SELECT ST_ClusterWithin(<geometry_column>, 10) arr
    FROM <your_point_table>
  ),

  clst_ext AS (
    SELECT a.cluster_id,
           ST_CollectionHomogenize(a.geom) AS geom
    FROM clst,
         unnest(clst.arr) WITH ORDINALITY a(geom, cluster_id)
  )

SELECT ce.cluster_id,
       pt.*
FROM <your_point_table> AS pt
JOIN clst_ext AS ce
  ON pt.<geometry_column> && ce.geom
```

with the minor backdraw that this obviously returns no polygons...
Does that sound like what you need?
**EDIT:**
As @dbaston thankfully pointed out and I keep forgetting, [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) is **way** better suited here;

```
SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(pt.<geometry_column>, 10, 1) OVER() AS cluster_id,
       *
FROM <your_point_layer> AS pt
```

to assign the *cluster_ids* to your points;

```
SELECT cluster_id,
       ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
FROM (
  SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geometry_column>, 10, 1) OVER() AS cluster_id,
         <geometry_column> AS geom
  FROM <your_point_layer>
) AS cluster
GROUP BY cluster_id
ORDER BY cluster_id
```

to get the minimal enclosing geometry of each cluster.

Comment: `unnest(clst.arr) with ordinality`, sweet. I have absolutely no idea if this answers the question or not, but it is a fabulous answer to some question :-)

Comment: @ThingumaBob I tried your method, and seems similiar to point aggregation in ArcGIS. This doesn't cluster all points. I have some points which are in a distance of 2, 7 meters are not clustered. I want all points which are separated by 10 m max be grouped on a polygon.

Comment: You can use `row_number () over ())::integer` to populate a sequential id col

Comment: @Vince Of course, thanks, but I was just adding to the inital query, so the second one is a mere mockup to exclude non-polygons. I´ll add a better one ASAP (since then the whole ordinal extraction is only overhead)...

Comment: Seems that it takes only the points within 10 m but not those which may be in 2,5 or 8 for instance.

Comment: Also, inside the cluster, the distance between all points should be 10m. because this methode groups adjacent points with 10 but I can have in the same cluster two points which are in 20. All points inside the polygone must be within 10 m

Comment: @zakariamouqcit hm...it´s not like `ST_ClusterWithin` would simply miss some points due to having a bad day, I just ran all queries on a table with proper UTM projection and got 100% correct results. are your points projected properly?

Comment: @zakariamouqcit to your 10m limit: imagine a couple of points in a straight line, each at a distance of 9m to each other ( p1 <- 9m -> p2 <- 9m -> p3); which one do you want to have within a cluster? p1 is 18m from p3, yet each has a distance of less than 10m to p2. I fear that you need another attribute or another restriction to focus your clusters the way you want them

Comment: Definitely use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` if you want to assign IDs back to the original points; see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273613/18189

Comment: @dbaston ah, damn, yes I keep forgetting that...I will change my queries ,) thanks! didn´t you even implement `ST_ClusterDBSCAN`? that´s some aggressive promoting...

Comment: In this case p should be clustered in an other group one grouo shoud contain only those which are separated to each other by  10m