# How to check if a geometry is contained in a geometry collection in postgis?

Tags: postgis

How can I check if a geometry is contained in a geometry collection ? Specifically , I am using `ST_ClusterWithin` in PostGIS to get a cluster which returns each cluster as a geometry collection. Now I want to extract the cluster_id for each geometry. For this I need to check if the geometry is within the geometry collection. How can I do it ? It is related to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194156/using-postgis-st-clusterwithin-on-a-table) question I asked on stackexchange some days ago.

Comment: For the application you describe, it should be sufficient to figure out which geometry collection each input intersects.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a combination of [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) and [ST_Dump()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Dump.html)

and compare results to your geometry. You will need to specify the geometry type you want to extract:

1 == POINT, 2 == LINESTRING, 3 == POLYGON

```
WITH c AS (
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_CollectionExtract(geom),2)).geom AS geom 
FROM my_geo_collection)

SELECT c.geom, t.geom FROM
c, my_geometry AS t

WHERE c.geom = t.geom
```

This might not work if your reference geometry is a multigeometry, since ST_Dump expands multi geometries into simple geometry types

Comment: Are you sure it works? ST_Dump returns a set. In my case I have `ERROR: operator does not exist: geometry = geometry_dump` error.

Comment: Right, you have to use (st_dump ()).geom. I corrected my answer