# Is there an open source equivalent to ArcGIS "collect events"?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis

I am looking for an equivalent tool to ArcGIS "collect events" (within the Spatial Statistics -> Utilities toolbox).  I wish to aggregate coincident point data in a space where many points lie in exactly the same place making visualisation difficult.

For example, to go from:

[image]

to:
[image]

thus providing a visual guide on density on points before proceeding to other forms of spatial analysis.

Is it possible to perform this on a different platform, preferably QGIS (or the associated PostGIS spatial db)?

Comment: What are the requirements that you are looking for this tool to meet?  I think these should be part of your question rather than saying that they are the same as something that can be found by finding and then following a link.

Comment: The QGIS point displacement renderer can do this. Also there is a cluster renderer being developed for QGIS: north-road.com/qgis-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding

Comment: @Vesanto the point displacement renderer does not do what I want.  I do not want to displace overlapping points, I want to cluster them.  I look forward to seeing the cluster renderer when it is released as it seems that this is the tool I am looking for.

Comment: Would clustering with small tolerances work for you? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis

Comment: Yes - this is very much the outcome that I'm after!  Apologies for the delay in posting here.  I would happily accept this as an answer to my query.  Thanks :)