# PostGIS - Dynamic Server-Side Clustering based on Zoom level

Tags: postgis, postgresql, leaflet, clustering, spatial-cluster

I'm working on a **Ruby on Rails** application that is showing road signs on the **map**(leaflet). So, user can browse map and road signs, great. But, if there are a lot of signs and user wants to zoom out, there are obvious problems for my app.

- First problem is to **prevent loading a lot of elements** (signs) at the same time.
- And the second problem is to have **clear view of elements** on the map.

This:

[image]

Insted of this:

[image]

Solution by my research is to **cluster elements by locations** as user is zoom-ing in and out. More precisely, using **k-means** algorithm.

My questions are :

1. Are there some *done* *solutions* for this?
2. If done solutions not exists, how to use k-means algorithm with zoom level?

I'm using **Postgres** database with **Postgis** extension and Ruby on Rails build API.

Comment: There are superb answers here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis

Comment: @alexander That are clustering algorithms but not anwsering my question

Comment: It is more usual to do this server side, for example, Leaflet's marker cluster control. This way you omly have one server round trip.

Comment: @JohnPowell app is divided on server side API (Rails) and Front end (React), so if I want to use marker cluster control I need to send all of data at once from API to Front end to cluster control to work. Am I wrong?

Comment: That is correct. So it will be slower the first time to load, but much, much quicker on zoom.

Comment: @JohnPowell but the goal is to optimize loading elements on a page, not sure if that is the best approach I'm looking for

Comment: @bKapusta Hey ! I'm facing pretty much the same situation as you did not so long ago. Did you find something interesting you might want to share please ? =)
Any hint would be much appreciated ! ;-)

Comment: @Pagehey Well, depends. You can do server-side clustering but it's a bit complicated and a bit slow. I found another solution for this to filter markers and then cluster them trough front-side.