# Select subset that is spatially equally distributed

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, point, sample

Let's say I have a table `point` with ~10.000 rows. Each row contains a `POINT(x, y)`.

I also have a table `polygon` with `POLYGONS(...)`.

The points in the `point` table are unequally distributed in space. There are areas with a lot of points, there are areas with little points. I want to draw sample of the table `points` of let's say 100, that is as much as possible equally distributed in one of the polygons from table `polygon`.

```
point
id    geom    name
1     ...     point1
2     ...     point2
3     ...     ...
4     ...     ...
...   ...     ...
...   ...     ...

polygon
id    geom    name
1     ...     poly1
2     ...     poly2
3     ...     ...
4     ...     ...
...   ...     ...
...   ...     ...
```

What is the best way to do this with `postgres`/`postgis`?

This is a screenshot of the points and the underlying polygons. These are 97300 points. The speed of the query giving me the sample does not really matter, since I only draw this sample once.

[image]

Comment: @BERA Yes, lets say 100 points in Spain, spreaded as much as possible over the whole area of Spain. What do you mean by *optimize the spread, or is just "spread out enough"?*

Comment: Select all points in, say, Spain -> `ST_ClusterKMeans` with 100 custers -> select the closest point to the cluster centroid per cluster.

Comment: I mean that there can be many different solutions/results, is it important to find the optimal

Comment: @BERA Not really. A "rough" spatial equally distribution of the points is enough. Its not scientific...

Comment: Compute a kernel density smoothing, then use the inverse of that as a weighted random sampler of the points. Not sure how you'd implement that in PostGIS without doing something in PL/R or PL/some_other_language though...

Comment: @geozelot won't K-means clustering tend to lump outliers in with denser clusters?  Whereas for a "least-dense" distribution outliers should be included.

Comment: Seems like @Spacedman has already provided a possible solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284026/2308716.  It involves iteratively computing the Voronoi of the points and removing the point with smallest cell.  But probably doesn't scale to large datasets.

Comment: If the requirement was to create a subset of points with a minimum separation, this approach could be used: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364847/14766.  But requiring a fixed number of result points is harder.  Possibly a decremental Delaunay algorithm could be used, but hard to do this in raw PostGIS.

Comment: @dr_jts yeah...scientifically, kmeans probably won't satisfy an unbiased, truly equal-distribution sample. On the other hand, I thnk it would produce a sample that represents the actual distribution quite naturally, plus having the most diverse spread between sample points. BUT: it seems I may have misread the actual outcome...how about finding the closest points to the cell centroids of a hexagon grid with 100 cells? Can't be much more equally spaced than that..

Comment: The hard part is to create a grid which covers an irregularly shaped region.