# Clustering spatial data in database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mysql, mysql-spatial

I have a simple website that is hosted on 000webhost. This service provides storing data in MySql database for a free plan. I wanted to extend some functionality for my site by clustering loads of point data.

Recently I found a related question about clustering data with multiple solutions. They work fine in PostgreSQL but in MySQL some functions from PostGIS functionality are exist but not in a full set.

For example:

```sql
SELECT  ST_ClusterWithin("GEOM", 100) gc 
FROM    geodata
```

This request works in PostgreSQL but not in MySQL (tested in phpMyAdmin). MySQL returns `FUNCTION mydb.ST_ClusterWithin does not exist`. Same with other parts of SQL requests from this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11778/77806

Is there any solution for making MySQL DB work with PostGIS functions?

If not then is there any reliable (and free if possible) hosting services that provide PostgreSQL functionality?

I just started working with spatial data in DB so may not be correct about SQL fundamentals.

Comment: if i were you id just spin up a light weight digital ocean server for $5 a month and just host your postgres db there. very simple I do it all the time

Comment: @ziggy as I was expecting... thanks for confirming my thoughts!

Comment: @ziggy found a solution for free: french hosting https://www.alwaysdata.com/. It provides storing PostgreSQL databases with PotGIS and many other extensions.